# Copy one sheet in xls format from one Excel workbook to another sheet in xlsx format in a different Excel using apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

I need to copy one sheet from Excel 2003 format to another Excel which has one sheet already. I want a new sheet with values from the Excel 2003 sheet.

Comment: @dloptin : Question is about copying two separate Excel formats. `xls` into `xlsx`. Link suggested, shows example of copying one `.xls` sheet into another `.xls` sheet.

Comment: I want to copy one sheet to a different excel workbook